# Button inside listview, being opened in a dialog, not firing button click event

Tags: jquery, asp.net, listview, button

Button inside listview, being opened in a dialog, not firing button click event. Here is the relevant code:

```
<div id="AssetsListView">

<asp:ListView ID="lstviewAssetAssign" runat="server">

<LayoutTemplate>

            <asp:Button ID="btnSaveAssetAssignFromListView" runat="server" Text="Save" OnClick="btnSaveAssetAssignFromListView_Click" />
            <asp:Button ID="btnClearCheckboxesFromListView" runat="server" Text="Clear" OnClick="btnClearCheckboxesFromListView_Click" />

</LayoutTemplate>

</asp:ListView>
</div>
```

I am opening this Listview in a dialog using:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        $("#AssetsListView").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            show: "show",
            hide: "hide",
            modal: true,
            draggable: false,
            resizable: false,
            width: 750
        });

        $(".gridviewbutton").unbind("click");
        $(".gridviewbutton").bind("click", function () {
            $("#AssetsListView").dialog("open");
        });
```

And here is the Event Handler declaration:

```
protected void btnSaveAssetAssignFromListView_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Some Code here            
    }

    protected void btnClearCheckboxesFromListView_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Some code here
    }
```

I tried adding breakpoints at the beginning of the event handlers, and am pretty sure that the events are not being fired on button click.

Some help would be appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: Did my answer work for you?

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your answer earlier and sorry for not replying. I v changed my job now but I think your answer was relevant at that time :)

Comment: Good luck with the new job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A jQuery ui dialog box is rendered *outside* the `<form runat='server'></form>` tags of an `aspx` page and hence does not trigger any server side events. You need to **append** the dialog box, when it opens, to the form element.

If you are using jQuery ui version > `1.10.0`, they have provided an `appendTo` option

```
$( ".selector" ).dialog({ appendTo: "form" });
```

Otherwise,

```
$('.selector').dialog({
      open:function(){{
         $(this).parent().appendTo($("form"));
     }}
});
```

In the above code, `form` represents the appropriate selector for the `<form></form>` element on your aspx page.